# Transparent message boxes in VP UML?

Tags: visual-paradigm

I'm making sequence diagrams for a project I'm developing. Nothing overly complex, just a few lifelines with calls back and forth.

The problem is, the white background box of my message descriptions cover over things like my lifeline boxes and dotted lines when in close quarters. You can see the issue in the image below, though I tried to space them out enough to minimize it, the background box still bleeds over the blue lifeline boxes.

[image]

I tried checking out Styles > Formatting when right clicking the message, but transparency doesn't seem to have an effect. If I understand right, the transparency slider I see only applies to the border of the box, and when I click "Background" instead of "Foreground" I see a different view with no transparency sliders, only a list of colours.

How can I make the backgrounds of these messages transparent as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can right click on the blank area of your diagram and select **Connectors** > **Paint Connector Through Label** to make the caption become transparent.

[image]

You can also find the same option under **Window** > **Project Options** > **Diagramming** > **Connector** which will take effect to any diagrams you created afterward.

Comment: Works for lines, but will it also apply to bleeding over the box elements as well?

Comment: Yes, once you turn on the Paint Connector Through Label then the background of the connector caption will become transparent.